# how to create new database in H2?

Tags: h2, railo

I have a site running locally on MySQL i want to run it on H2 database. I have just run h2.jar file for console on the browser but whenever I Log in I have seen the list `jdbc:h2:/var/www/mysite/data/db; MODE=MySQL, information_schema and users.`I can create tables in it but don't know how to create new database?

I am using Mode = MySQL 
           type = H2 Database Engine in Embedded mode.

Answer (score 15):

From http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#creating_new_databases,

> By default, if the database specified in the URL does not yet exist, a
>   new (empty) database is created automatically. The user that created
>   the database automatically becomes the administrator of this database.

Comment: I have tried this and I want to name the database as `mysite` and more question i have SQL script for creating tables and inserting data. How can i run script or export it using H2 ?

Answer (score 3):

The settings of the H2 Console are stored in a configuration file called `.h2.server.properties` in your user home directory. For Windows installations, the user home directory is usually `C:\Documents and Settings\[username]` or `C:\Users\[username]`. The configuration file contains the settings of the application and picked up when the H2 Console is started.

> Below config to create a new database on startup:

1. add newline in property file.

`0=Generic H2 (Server)|org.h2.Driver|jdbc\:h2\:tcp\://localhost/~/db_name|sa`

2. open the `command prompt` go to the `\bin` directory where h2 has installed:

`e.g. cd C:\Program Files (x86)\H2\bin`

3. and run following the command
   `java -cp h2-1.4.194.jar org.h2.tools.Server`.

**Other General Settings:**

`webAllowOthers`: allow other computers to connect.

`webPort`: the port of the H2 Console

`webSSL`: use encrypted TLS (HTTPS) connections.