# Can't create H2 database "due to SQL syntax error"

Tags: sql, spring, spring-boot, h2

I can't run my unit test due to an error

DataSource bean definition

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class MyBeanTest {

    @Configuration
    static class ContextConfiguration {

        @Bean
        DataSource dataSource() {
            return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .addScript("com/example/ddl.sql")
                .setSeparator(";")
                .build();
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

`ddl.sql` content

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb;
```

Error

> Caused by: 
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in com.example.MyBeanTest$ContextConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of class path resource [com/example/ddl.sql]: 
>   CREATE DATABASE mydb; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE DATABASE[*] MYDB "; expected "OR, FORCE, VIEW, ALIAS, SEQUENCE, USER, TRIGGER, ROLE, SCHEMA, CONSTANT, DOMAIN, TYPE, DATATYPE, AGGREGATE, LINKED, MEMORY, CACHED, LOCAL, GLOBAL, TEMP, TEMPORARY, TABLE, PRIMARY, UNIQUE, HASH, SPATIAL, INDEX"; SQL statement:

SpringBoot 1.5.3

Comment: ...and what's inside `com/example/ddl.sql`? BTW, usually that goes into `src/main/resources`.

Comment: H2 doesn't have a `create database` statement, so that statement is a syntax error.

Comment: @ɐuıɥɔɐɯ I've posted its content

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel So, how to test DAOs having statements with db prefix in that case? like `select * from mydb.some_table;`

Comment: That would be [`create schema`](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#create_schema) instead. In the case of H2 the database is the file, and it either needs to exist, or is created when you connect to it. The schema is a subdivision inside the database.

Comment: Thank you, Mark!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to create new database in H2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24372931/how-to-create-new-database-in-h2)